# Does this code provide memory leaks?

Tags: c++, qt, memory-leaks, valgrind

Finally i have installed Ubuntu and set up Qt+Valgrind to prevent memory leaks which i could not do in Windows. So i can not understand does this code provide a memory leak? In fact that Valgrind says i have only 500+ issues but nothing about the leak. I

```
#include <QWidget>
#include <QFrame>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])

{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QWidget * wdgt = new QWidget;  //this line should be the cause of leakage 
                                   //if it exist (as far as i know)
    QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout;
    QFrame * frame = new QFrame;

    frame->setFrameStyle(QFrame::Panel | QFrame::Plain);
    frame->setLineWidth(5);
    layout->addWidget(frame);

    wdgt->setLayout(layout);
    wdgt->setFixedSize(800,600);
    wdgt->show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: No it doesn't because the OS takes care of it.

Comment: but in this case it dose not `int * a = new int;`

Comment: Every `new` should have the corresponding `delete`. Alternatively use smart pointers

Comment: @EdHeal not in case of Qt, there if object has a parent, parent destroys it

Comment: i know how to prevent it. i do not know if my code (top) provides a lekage, due to Qt memory management.

Comment: You're allocating memory in `main` for `wdgt`, `layout` and `frame`. Although, eventually you have to `delete` what you've previously allocated in this case because `main` will exit and with it the program will terminate any memory allocated will be wiped out from the operating system.

Comment: You do not pass the `QWidget` to an instance taking ownership, hence it is a memory leak.

Comment: First of all why do you create `wdgt` on the heap?

Comment: @Dieter Lücking  so Valgrind is also a shitty software to check for leaks?

Comment: @ Slava my point was to check if Valgrind is ok for preventing memory leaks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating and deallocating a Qt widget object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4267854/creating-and-deallocating-a-qt-widget-object)

Comment: @Mikhail I doubt it will detect single cases. Especially for objects that created in `main()`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See this post: [Creating and deallocating a Qt widget object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4267854/creating-and-deallocating-a-qt-widget-object)

It explaines that if one Qt object has a parent, it will be automatically deleted when the parent is destroyed.

In your code:

- `wdgt` is the parent of `layout` because you did `wdgt->setLayout(layout)`.
- `wdgt` is the parent of `frame` because you did `layout->addWidget(frame)` and `layout`'s parent is `wdgt`. As commented by thuga, layout pass the ownership to their own parent.

In your code, only `wdgt` is orphan (no Qt parent to delete it automatically).

To fix this, you can either give him a parent:

```
QWidget * wdgt = new QWidget(&app);
```

So that `wdgt` is a child of `app` and will then be deleted automatically when `app` is destroyed.

or delete it yourself:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    ...
    int res = a.exec();
    delete wdgt; // this will delete wdgt, but also frame and layout
    return res;
}
```

or, fianlly, create it as an object, so that it is deleted when going out of scope:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QWidget wdgt;

    QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout;
    QFrame * frame = new QFrame;

    frame->setFrameStyle(QFrame::Panel | QFrame::Plain);
    frame->setLineWidth(5);
    layout->addWidget(frame);

    wdgt.setLayout(layout);
    wdgt.setFixedSize(800,600);
    wdgt.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

By the way, note that if you do `QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout(wdgt)`, there is no need to do `wdgt->setLayout(layout)`. So those two piece of codes are equivalent:

```
QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout(wdgt); // parenting upon construction
```

is the same as:

```
QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout; // no parent
wdgt->setLayout( layout ); // reparenting
```

Comment: The cleanest way I believe is create `QWidget wdgt` on stack!

Comment: Actually the parent of both `layout` and `frame` would be `wdgt`. Layouts don't take ownerships of widgets, they just pass the ownership to their own parent.

Comment: I thought it might be important to clarify that, as I've seen people delete layouts assuming it will get rid of the widgets inside those layouts. This is because they think that the parent of those widgets is the layout, and destroying the parent will destroy its children.

Answer (score 0):

Yes your Code leaks memory because you create objects using `new` without using Qt's memory management.

Go for

```
QApplication a(argc, argv);
QWidget * wdgt = new QWidget(&app);
QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout(wdgt); // optional, setLayout does that
QFrame * frame = new QFrame(layout); // optional, addWidget does that
```

to use Qt's memory management.

---

Alternatively you can use C++11 shared pointers:

```
QApplication a(argc, argv);
std::shared_ptr<QWidget> wdgt = std::make_shared<QWidget>();

QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout;
QFrame * frame = new QFrame;
```

As soon as the last user of a shared pointer goes out of scope, your objects are deleted automatically.

Comment: Only `QWidget(&app)` was needed. Other items are parented (`QWidget::setLayout` makes the `QWidget` become parent of the `QLayout` and `QLayout::addWidget` makes the `QLayout` become parent of the `QWidget`). Only `wdgt` was orpahn in the OP.

Comment: And also widgets are reparented automagically when you add them to layout and layouts when added to widgets and so on

Comment: And also shared ptrs will lead to double deletion in this case (because of reparenting)

Comment: Thank you all! It helps me so much.

Comment: I would definitely avoid mixing shared_ptr with Qt objects. Those are two different mechanism of "auto-deletion" and you'll most likely end up with double deletions...

Answer (score 0):

Your code leaks memory, but first of all you shouldn't write code where you even have to care about resources leaking. Let the compiler handle it for you:

```
// main.cpp
#include <QtWidgets>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QWidget widget;
    QVBoxLayout layout(&widget);
    QFrame frame;

    frame.setFrameStyle(QFrame::Panel | QFrame::Plain);
    frame.setLineWidth(5);
    layout.addWidget(&frame);

    widget.setFixedSize(800,600);
    widget.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: can not agree with you

Comment: I am not sure but the above comments assume that when pointers are passed they are taken ownership and therefore will be deleted. This is not possible if they are on the stack. Please clarify

Comment: @EdHeal This works too, as long as the objects are created in the right order. See [Object trees & ownership](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/objecttrees.html).

Comment: @EdHeal *pointers are passed they are taken ownership and therefore will be deleted* `QObject` does not have an infinite memory of its children. When a child is destructed, its parent will obviously not attempt to delete it. C++ has perfectly useful semantics when it comes to the order of destruction of values. I'm surprised that people write C++ code without realizing that this order is there for a good reason, and that the programmer is supposed to leverage it to her benefit.

Comment: @Mikhail *can not agree with you* I've posted working, correct code that uses the C++ compiler and language semantics to good effect. Would you care to elaborate what you find disagreeable?

Comment: @KubaOber not to use new and delete

Comment: @Mikhail What for? It doesn't help with anything. Modern C++ should read more like Python than C. If you see manual memory management everywhere, you're doing something very, very wrong.

Comment: @KubaOber I see your point, and i have had a look at my code so i'm going to change some lines. thank you for putting me in a right way.

Comment: Will you code try to delete stuff that is on the stack?

Comment: @EdHeal No. And there's zero reason for it to do so. The confusion that spawned that line of thinking stems from misunderstanding the very basic of C++ semantics. There's a simple transformation that you can do to the code to break it and have `QObject` incorrectly attempt to delete variables with automatic storage duration. It reduces down to making a mistake and not understanding the proper resolution, instead shooting down what should be modern, idiomatic C++. Use values and references as the first line of attack.

Comment: @EdHeal No. But it unnecessarily dynamically allocates minuscule object handles. Qt extensively uses PIMPLs, so both `QObject` and `QWidget` are essentially fat pointers. By allocating them dynamically, unnecessarily, you simply prematurely pessimize your code. It's pointless, when you can just use values.

Comment: @ReinstateMonica https://stackoverflow.com/a/37375210/12139819

Comment: @vtronko That answer can be summarized as "you'll shoot yourself in the foot if you choose to shoot yourself in the foot". Sure you have to exercise a modicum of care, but this is really a problem that has never bit me, and I strive to let C++ manage object lifetimes because it's free. `QObject` has to iterate a tree at runtime to delete the children, whereas the compiler does the "iteration" at compile-time. Do leverage the object lifetime management that's the core of C++ and makes it different from most other popular programming languages. It's why we use C++ in the first place.

Comment: @ReinstateMonica `QObject`s are not always destroyed in the same order they were declared in first place. It might very well be that widget's implementation destroys `layout`   upon particular event later. It's not like nobody except you doesn't understand how inferior are heap allocated objects to stack allocated ones in cases where variable scope is statically known. Everything depends on application logic and user input.