# Shall I delete QObject pointers after using them?

Tags: c++, qt

Shall I delete `QObject` pointers after using them in Qt 5.7.0?

For example, I have got the code:

```
std::string login;
std::string password;
if (serviceId == 11) {
    QObject* loginField = this->parent()->findChild<QObject*>("wifiLogintxt1");
    QObject* passwordField = this->parent()->findChild<QObject*>("wifiPasswordtxt1");
    login = loginField->property("text").toString().toStdString();
    password = passwordField->property("text").toString().toStdString();
} else {
    QObject* loginField = this->parent()->findChild<QObject*>("inputField1");
    login = loginField->property("text").toString().toStdString();
}
```

Will the code lead to a memory leak, because we don't delete `QObject` pointers?

Comment: No, don't delete those pointers in Qt

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating and deallocating a Qt widget object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4267854/creating-and-deallocating-a-qt-widget-object)

Comment: Pointer should be deleted by their owners. I suppose parent widgets are owners of your `QObjects` variables. So you should not delete them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, You shouldn't delete these objects, they are managed by their parent `QObject`s, see [QObject trees and ownership](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/objecttrees.html):

When using `findChild`, you are getting a pointer to the same object managed by this parent.

So, `loginField`, `passwordField` are deleted when their parent widget is deleted (`this` instance in your case). If you delete them, they will disappear from the GUI. You have to keep them until the parent widget decides they are no longer needed (that is the time when it is destructed):

> You can also delete child objects yourself, and they will remove themselves from their parents. For example, when the user removes a toolbar it may lead to the application deleting one of its QToolBar objects, in which case the tool bar's QMainWindow parent would detect the change and reconfigure its screen space accordingly.

Comment: Imagine a situation when we repeatedly call the code above. It will create new `QObject* loginField` so it will use more memory, right?

Comment: No, `loginField` will always get a pointer to the same object being managed by the parent (as I said in my answer). so, no additional allocation is done.